# Displaying list object in JSP Number format Exception

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

**In Jsp Page**

```
<c:forEach var="trans" items="${transactionlist}">
            <tr scope="row" >
            <td>${trans.Acc_No}</td>
            <td>${trans.Ftrans_Acc}</td>
            <td>${trans.deposit}</td>
            <td>${trans.withdraw}</td>
            <td>${trans.Balance}</td>
            <td>${trans.Transid}</td> 
            </c:forEach>
          </tr>
```

**In Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="miniStatement/{accno}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView MViewStatement(@PathVariable String accno,ModelMap map){
        map.addAttribute("transactionlist",managerservice.listViewCustomer(accno));
        System.out.println(managerservice.listViewCustomer(accno).toString());
    //in printing above statement I am getting list object of my Transaction 
        return new ModelAndView("PrintMiniStatement");
    }
```

**But I am getting number format exception in jsp page 
Then I Tried this :
In Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="miniStatement/{accno}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView MViewStatement(@PathVariable String accno,ModelMap map){
        map.addAttribute("transactionlist",managerservice.listViewCustomer(accno).get(0));
        System.out.println(managerservice.listViewCustomer(accno).toString());
        return new ModelAndView("PrintMiniStatement");
    }
```

**In Jsp**

```
 <c:forEach var="trans" items="${transactionlist}">
            <tr scope="row" >
            <td>${trans}</td>
            </c:forEach>
          </tr>
```

I am getting single row horizontally while rest data I can't get though I know I did get index 0 value but my question is how to retrieve this list data in jsp page in table form

In Dao I am retrieving top 10 list

```
@Override
    public List<Transaction> listViewCustomer(String accno) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    String sql="Select * from transactions where Acc_No="+accno+" limit 10"+";";
    SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);



return query.list();

}
```

Comment: You want to resolve NumberFormatException or want to know how to display your result in table form. Because I see two different questions here.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria Display my result in table form but getting error numberformatexception

Comment: Please show the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not using **HQL** query.
2. You have specified `return type` wrongly.

**Solution 1**: Change SQL query to HQL query

Use `.setMaxResults(10)` for limit purpose

```
@Override
public List<Transaction> listViewCustomer(String accno) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    // Add your desc criteria in the query some  'order by'
    String HQL="from transactions t where t.Acc_No= :accno";
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery(HQL)
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .setParameter("accno",accno);
    return query.list();
}
```

**Solution 2**: Change `return type` query to `List<Object []>`  and map it to your transactions class in service method or ...

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> listViewCustomer(String accno) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    String sql="Select * from transactions where Acc_No="+accno+" limit 10";
    SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: I am getting sql error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: I replaced your answer createSQLQuery with createQuery then I got this transactions is not mapped [from transactions t where t.Acc_No= :accno]

Comment: In a Model I have like this .......@Entity(name="transactions")
@Table(name="transactions")
public class Transaction

Comment: I just provide you format/guideline, you write your own SQLQuery

Comment: Show me tour entity class, Replace transactions with `Transaction` class

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Transaction is not mapped [from Transaction t where t.Acc_No= :accno]...........did what you have told still getting this

Comment: "from from com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.Transaction t where t.Acc_No= :accno"; this is working but not I am getting this error org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [accno]

Comment: I tired your solution 2 instead but I am getting this in return type in jsp also [[Ljava.lang.Object;@3b5b6831]

Comment: @MohammadSameerKhan you have to set `List<Object []>` to your `List<Transaction>`

Comment: I resolved i missed my mapping class in hibernate config xml file that's why I could perform operation only on 3 classes rest other 2 added class was creating a problem I added the mapping class in config file and it worked like a charm